# VB.NET Score Not Adding

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm making a rock paper scissors game in visual basic and the basics are the player choice is determined by a radio button of either rock paper or scissors and the computer's choice is based on a random number between 1 - 3 rock is 3 paper is 2 scissors is 1.
When the play button is clicked it runs an if statement to check if the rock button has been checked and the random int is equal to rock in which case its a draw but if you choose rock and the random int Val is scissors then you win and it adds 1 to your score

The problem is the score doesn't go beyond 1 and I don't understand

Heres the code:

```
Public Class gameForm
    Private Sub btnPlay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlay.Click
        Try
            Dim playerscore = 0
            Dim comscore = 0
            Dim rock As Integer = 3
            Dim paper As Integer = 2
            Dim scissors As Integer = 1
            Dim number As Integer = CInt(Int((3 * Rnd()) + 1))

            Randomize()

            If rbRock.Checked And number = rock Then
                lblPlayerChoice.Text = "You Chose Rock"
                lblPcChoice.Text = "Computer Chose Rock"
                lblGameOutcome.Text = "Draw"
            ElseIf rbRock.Checked And number = paper Then
                lblPlayerChoice.Text = "You Chose Rock"
                lblPcChoice.Text = "Computer Chose Paper"
                lblGameOutcome.Text = "Computer Wins"
                comscore = comscore + 1
                lblComScoreVal.Text = CStr(comscore)
            ElseIf rbRock.Checked And number = scissors Then
                lblPlayerChoice.Text = "You Chose Rock"
                lblPcChoice.Text = "Computer Chose Scissors"
                lblGameOutcome.Text = "You Win"
                playerscore = playerscore + 1
                lblPlayerScoreVal.Text = CStr(playerscore)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show("Unknown Error Occurred", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

        End Try


    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initialising a value for the player's score to zero when you click the button, rather than storing it somewhere else. Every time the button is clicked the score is set to zero and then the calculation is applied.  Instead of setting to zero, you should set it to either the value of lblComScoreVal.text, or zero if that is not set to anything.

Comment: im not new, new accoutn because my old one got banned from asking questions because they apprently werent clear enough but i didnt know how else to word them

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and if my answer solved your problem you can mark it as so - I get the reputation and anyone reading the question sees the answer that worked for you.

Comment: Thanks ill use this as a reference when asking future questions, thank you for your help i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You have to bring that playerscore and comscore out of your Sub btnPlay_Click ...

it should something like this

```
Public Class gameForm
    Private playerscore as Integer = 0
    Private comscore as Integer = 0

    Private Sub btnPlay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlay.Click
        Try
```